# rsync is failing when trying to sync a big home folder

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

I try to copy a very big home folder (`/home/myUser`) to a new computer over network. Although I regularly use `rsync` its failing after copying 55 / 80GB with the error message

```
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [generator=3.1.0]
```

Is there some data limit / time limit what rsync can handle at max?

I would also consider using `scp -r` but apparantly it doesn't copy links correctly.

This was the command I used

```
    sudo rsync -r -l -p --progress "someSudoUser@nameOfRemoteComputer:/home/myUser/" "/home/myUser"
```

Has anyone an idea why `rsync` is breaking down?

Comment: And what are the previous errors that rsync generates? :)

Comment: This is often due to a lack of permissions on one end or the other, you may need to use the `--rsync-path "sudo rsync"` on the receiving server, and make sure that the sudo user can complete a sudo rsync command without entering a password.

Comment: @Arronical Ah ok, can you please give an example of the full command?

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: In the meantime I solved it in the lamest possible way by just taking and external USB drive and `scp -r`. Your answer sounds very promising, next time I'll get this problem I'll definitely try your solution. I was just suprised since I'm working with rsync for quite  some time and never had problems except for now when I tried to move that large home directory. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

The error you're having is often due to a lack of permissions on one end or the other, as you're doing a `sudo rsync` on the sending end, that discounts this option, so it must be on the receiving end.

Currently, you're sunning a `sudo rsync` on the sending end, but running a non-sudo version on the receiver, even though you are doing it with a sudo user. To remedy this you may need to use the `--rsync-path "sudo rsync"` option on the receiving machine, and make sure that the sudo user can complete a sudo rsync command without entering a password.

Before doing this you'll need to set up your with passwordless access to the rsync command, on the receiving machine. This will edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, be careful doing this as you can lock yourself out of sudo access if you muck up this file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Enter the following lines at the bottom of the file. The first line is just a comment to help you remember why the next line has been added.

```
# Allows someSudoUser to use rsync with no password.
someSudoUser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync
```

Here are a couple of useful links about sudo access:[Sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Once this is complete, the rsync command would be:

```
sudo rsync -rlp --progress --rsync-path "sudo rsync" "someSudoUser@nameOfRemoteComputer:/home/myUser/" "/home/myUser"
```

An alternative to this whole approach would be to identify which files are causing the problem, and exclude them from the rsync command, using the `--exclude` option of rsync.